# Reading a Text File in Java-12

Tags: java

Think about an text file like :

```
line1 ->5
line2 ->A 10
line3 ->B 15
line4 ->C 25
line5 ->D 5
line6 ->E 30
```

'5' is the number of {a,b,c,d,e}. How can i hold these variables in two arrays like :

```
Array1[5] = {A,B,C,D,E}
Array2[5] = {10,15,25,5,30}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Open the file, read the first line and store it inside a variable to initialize your arrays. Loop over the rest of the lines, split them on a single space character, store the first half in your first array and the second half in your second array. Done.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// read all lines in the file into a list
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filename"), Charset.defaultCharset());

// determine the length of the arrays based on the first line
int length = Integer.parseInt(lines.remove(0));    

// first column
String[] col1 = new String[length];

// second column
int [] col2 = new int[length];

// now for every remaining row, add to each column
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
   String [] pair = lines.remove(0).split(" ");
   col1[i] = pair[0];
   col2[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);
}
```

Or even easier...

```
// create a scanner of the file
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("filename"));

// read the first token as an int to know array length
int length = scan.nextInt();

String [] col1 = new String[length];
int [] col2 = new int[length];

// assuming valid data, loop through each row
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
  col1[i] = scan.next();
  col2[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// x = the contents of your file

```
while(x.hasNext) {
   String a = x.next(); // This will get the first bit (e.g A, B, C, etc)
   String b = x.next(); // This will get the last bit (e.g 10, 15, 25, etc)
   // now just put them in the array
   // for every extra bit of data you have on a line you just add another String y = x.next();
}
```

after it puts them in the array it will go to the next line.
That should read your file the way you want it to.